# Is the M2_HOME environment variable supposed to point to the Maven install directory or my .m2 directory?

Tags: maven

I have installed Maven on my system into

```
C:\development\ApacheSoftwareFoundation\apache-maven-3.2.3
```

In reading about installing Maven, I read that I need to set MAVEN_HOME and M2_HOME environment variables. I know the MAVEN_HOME environment variable is supposed to point to where I installed Maven (the path above), but is the M2_HOME environment variable supposed to also point to the Maven install directory, or to my .m2 directory?

Ultimately my question is, is MAVEN_HOME and M2_HOME the same thing, or different?

I know the .m2 home can be set in settings.xml, but is that the only place where Maven looks for it, in the settings.xml file, or, like I asked, is M2_HOME also where Maven looks for my .m2 directory?

Comment: From http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi there is no need setting MAVEN_HOME only M2_HOMe

Comment: So, in other words, M2_HOME is supposed to point to my Maven installation and not my .m2 directory ... correct?

Comment: Yes, M2_HOME should point to your mvn installation directory (as written in the doc). Please note you should also define the M2 env variable : M2=$M2_HOME/bin or under WIN M2=%M2_HOME%\bin